# How to keep files when clicking on save?

Tags: kaggle

I am creating files in output with a GUI (interactive) then I put a # before the gui command and commit to go in offline mode (non interactive) to run my full script.

But the notebook can find the files created in output with the GUI before commit even if I have put persistent if all combos.

How can I use reuse my files ? Or is there a way to use input in writing mode ?

I want to use files created in interactive mode in non interactive mode or use input in writing mode.

Thanks